# What does the numbers inside a node in fancyRpartPlot() mean when using method="anova"?

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree, anova, rpart

I'm new to the decision tree world and I've been trying to understand what the numbers inside the nodes of this fancyRpartPlot() image means. Below there's the code and the plot.

```
    cfit2 <- rpart(pgstat ~ age + eet + g2 + grade + gleason + ploidy, 
data = stagec, method = "anova")
```

[image: http://prntscr.com/8eg9pm]

Does anybody know what the numbers I've pointed in the plot mean?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I've figured it out. If someone else has the same doubts I had, here goes what I think those values mean:

Image: http://prntscr.com/8eie8q

Sorry about the link to see the image but I can't post images here yet.

Check them out observing the values you get when you print out the tree in textual form.

Answer (score 0):

the probability on the top gives the percent for the predictor class. N gives the number of data points used to reached that probability and the final number on each node shows the percent of population which resides in this node.